# How would you get the update method to be called in a class other than MyScene in Objective-C's Sprite-Kit project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

So I'm in the process of making a Objective-C Sprite-Kit based game. I'm fairly new to Objective-C so I seem to be stuck on something involving the update method.

Traditionally in the default Sprite-Kit project it generates for you create a View which contains a scene which contains all the nodes that you want to manipulate. It also comes with a pre-generated, empty update method which since then I have replaced with my own (which works great). But I do not want my update method to based in the MyScene class and this is where my problem lies. If I leave the update method in the MyScene class I can see using NSLog that is in fact continuously being called like it should be, but if I move it say to the ViewControler class it won't be called at all.

**My question is how would I go about getting it to call the update method in a class other than MyScene..?** You may be asking why I would want to do this so I'll explain below but its not fully necessary to answer the question, however if you do have any tips on my program please let me know!

**Traditional Sprite-Kit Project**

ViewController --> Creates a MyScene (which is just inheriting from SKScene)
MyScene --> Creates all the nodes, and has the update method to hand game logic/graphics.

**My Ideal Structure for my Sprite Game**

ViewController --> Creates a ForegroundScene and BackgroundScene(still inherits from SKScene)
ForegroundScene --> creates all the nodes/characters for the game
BackgroundScene --> Creates the Sky, clouds, general landscape stuff for the game.
GameController --> contains the update method which calls displayView and updateGame.

Edit: To clear up any confusion, ForgegroundScene and BackgroundScene are essentialy the same thing as the MyScene class which was originally generated, but now there are two classes re-named, one containing stuff for the background, the other for the foreground.

Update Game is still located in the GameController class and it just does things like collision test, updates position of nodes, deletes characters that were killed.

DisplayView is located in the ViewController and its name is self-explanatory it displays the view of the game which is composed of nodes from the BackgroundScene and the ForegroundScene.

Anyway, this is my idea set up for a game, not sure how pratical it is. I'm very open to suggestions.

Here is my intended update method incase you are interested in seeing it but like I said I test it with NSLog and it ticks accordingly but in any other class its never called.

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    const int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 35;
    const int SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND; //these ivars would be moved to top of intended class
    const int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;

    NSDate *referenceDate = [NSDate date];

    double timePassed_ms = [referenceDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;
    NSUInteger next_game_tick = timePassed_ms;
    int loops;

    bool game_is_running = true;
    while( game_is_running ) {

        loops = 0;
        while([referenceDate timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0 > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
            [self updateGame] //calls GameController to do logic updates/collision test, etc.
            NSLog(@"update game");

            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
        }
        [self displayGame]; //calls viewcontroler to display game
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use your two scenes in `[self updateGame]`.

Comment: I see several problems here: 1) you can only have one scene (presented, receiving update:) at any one time, your other "scene" must be a regular sknode or just nsobject referenced via an ivar in the actual scene. 2) Your referenceDate is overengineering, you only need to compare currentTime with the time of the previous update call to getbthe delta time. 3) Calling updateGame multiple times per frame (especially at 60 fps) really only makes sense if you plan on creating your own physics engine that needs multiple velocity/position integration. Otherwise it's overengineered.

Comment: 4) displayGame indicates you plan on "drawing" stuff yourself, which is not necessary in Sprite Kit. SK renders or "displays" the contents of the scene autonomously. There's little I can think of that you would need to do in displayGame that couldn't already be done in update. Overall it looks like you intend to implement a core game loop of a game engine but fail to consider that sprite kit already encapsulates this game engine logic. What you can do is add a component-based framework on top to implement game logic independent from the view but that's about it.

Comment: Hmm from my understanding the view can only present one scene but I was thinking I would be able to have two different views one layer on top of the other containing the foregroundScene, and the other containing the background Scene. If not then would I have to combine all the sprites into one scene? Like have my animated clouds and the sky be in the same scene as the characters and weapons. Sounds like it would get very big and unorganized when I prefer to split them up.

Comment: 2-3) I'll fix my gameloop thank you!. 4) Alright, it sounds like I don't need this at all and that I'd just include whatever minor drawing stuff in my original update. On that thought I have a question, say I'm listening for feedback of the person flicking the screen of some sort, when I get that motion I tell the weapon sprite to go into the air like its being thrown. Would you recommend I have these listeners in GameController or ViewControler or w/? Since it seems like I will be removing my displayGame idea I'm leaning towards the GameController class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the class that you want to notify every time you call `-update:` an instance variable of your scene, then just forward the message to that class. For example, create an instance variable in your scene of the class you want to notify.

```
@interface MyScene ()
@property (nonatomic) ClassToNotify *notify;
@end
```

Then in your `-update:` method, just notify the instance variable.

```
- (void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    // pass the message on
    [self.notify notifyThatUpdateWasJustCalledWithTime:currentTime];
}
```

In this case, `-notifyThatUpdateWasJustCalledWithTime:` would be a method of your `ClassToNotify` class.